# How to using counter in foreach migration table? (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, counter, laravel-5.3

My code is like this :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Akun;
use App\Models\Master_lookup;

class MasterLookupsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        foreach (Akun::all() as $key => $value) {
            $masterLookup = new Master_lookup;
            $masterLookup->id           = ++$key
            $masterLookup->parent_id    = NULL;
            $masterLookup->code         = $value->kdakun;
            $masterLookup->name         = $value->nmakun;
            $masterLookup->type         = 'akun';
            $masterLookup->information  = json_encode($value->kdjenbel);
            $masterLookup->save(); 
        }
    }
}
```

I use index `$key` to counter

But when executed, there is exist error :

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$masterLookup' (T_VARIABLE)
```

Is there any people who can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not add `id` manually. ID should be `AUTO INCREMENT`, so DB could automatically increase it. `id` in migration should be defined like this:

```
$table->increments('id');
```

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to use `increments()` for some reason, just use this:

```
$masterLookup->id = $key;
```

This should work, because you're iterating over Eloquent collection, so  `key` is unique.

Comment: There is exist error like this : `Use of undefined constant key - assumed 'key'`

Comment: Use `$key`, I've accidently deleted `$` sign

Comment: This seems correct, `$masterLookup->id = ++$key;` order starting from 1, not 0. My answer is only  less `;`

Answer (score 0):

In your code you didn't have added semi-column at the end of line.

`$masterLookup->id           = ++$key;`

use semi-column (;) at the end of line.